# understanding the behavior of MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor in Netty 3

Tags: netty, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I want to understand the behavior of [MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor](http://netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html) in Netty 3.

I'm implementing the sample example provided in [java docs](http://netty.io/3.10/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html) with small changes.

My Runnable class

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public MyRunnable(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;

    }

    public void run()  {
        String dataString = new String(data, 0, data.length);
        System.out.println("Started processing data " + dataString);
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
            //Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done processing data " + dataString);
    }
}
```

The MyObjectSizeEstimator class is

```
class MyObjectSizeEstimator extends DefaultObjectSizeEstimator {
    @Override
    public int estimateSize(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof MyRunnable) {
            return ((MyRunnable) o).getData().length;
        }
        return super.estimateSize(o);
    }
}
```

The Main class is

```
  public class MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutorDemo {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(
                  16, 65536, 1048576, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                  new MyObjectSizeEstimator(),
                  Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
          String[] dataArray = new String[10];
          for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
              dataArray[i] = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric((i + 1) ) + "   " + i;
          }

          for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
              pool.execute(new MyRunnable(dataArray[i].getBytes()));
          }

          while(pool.getActiveCount() != 0) {
              try {
                  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                  ie.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          pool.shutdown();
      }
  }
```

I'm expecting the main class to execute the tasks which are larger in size. but I see the tasks are always executing in random order every time when I run the program.

Any explanation or reason behind the behavior of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` basically just knows about how much memory a task will take and depending on it handles "back-pressure". It has nothing to do with ordering at all.

Also note that Netty 3 is EOL for a long time, you should use 4.1.